# unsigned int in C function

Tags: c, r

How to return variable of type unsigned int from C function to R?
Information is encoded in bits of variable. I can extract this information in C but I would prefer to do this in R.

Answer (score 3):

As R has no signed/unsigned types, you will have to cast your `unsigned int` to an `int` or `double`.

Or create a new R type to implement unsigned integer at the R level.

Comment: I did some search and found uint64 in int64 package. It has method to convert from double moreover function binary converts uint64 to bits representation.