# How to get '(unsigned int)' operation in R?

Tags: r, 64-bit, unsigned-integer

I would like to reproduce Version 2 of the following C code in R.
The problem is that R doesn't seem to have an operation equivalent to C's '(unsigned int)'
(there are no unsigned integers in R). I looked into some packages but couldn't easily
find it. To do the conversion manually (or with a function), would one need to add `.Machine$integer.max + 1` or so? (but that's probably needed in 64bit then to reproduce the C code)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int II1 = -1;
int II2 = -2;
int_least64_t a = 1403580;
int_least64_t b = 810728;

int main()
{
    int_least64_t p;
    /* Version 1 */
    p = a * II2 - b * II1;
        printf("%lld\n", (int_least64_t)(p)); /* -1996432 */
    /* Version 2 */
    p = a * (unsigned int)II2 - b * (unsigned int)II1;
    printf("%lld\n", (int_least64_t)(p)); /* 2546279949371760 */
    return 0;
}
```

This reproduces Version 1 in R (probably also 32 bit instead of 64):

```
II1 <- -1
II2 <- -2
a <- 1403580
b <- 810728
a * II2 - b * II1
```

Comment: This [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395421/unsigned-int-in-c-function)  may help you.

Comment: I actually saw that post, but it wasn't helpful. It don't need to return values from C, I want to replicate C.

Comment: I meant the reference to uint64 in int64 package.  That was no good?

Comment: It's beyond my imagination why someone can possibly downvote this legitimate question. It comes from the fact that I can replicate R's implementation of L'Ecuyer's Combined Multiple-Recursive Generator in R (R itself obviously uses C), but only if the 6 seeds are positive. If they are negative, the difference with 'unsigned int' matters.

Comment: I tried with Rmpfr since: "Package ‘int64’ was removed from the CRAN repository"

Comment: I should have checked. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# from bmp:::ConvertIntToUInt() 

int_to_unit <- function (x, adjustment=2^32) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  signs <- sign(x)
  x[signs < 0] <- x[signs < 0] + adjustment
  x
}

II1 <- -1L
II2 <- -2L
a <- 1403580L
b <- 810728L

(p <- a * II2 - b * II1)
## [1] -1996432

(p <- a * int_to_uint(II2) - b * int_to_uint(II1))
## [1] 2546279949371760
```

Note that you're not going to get integers back. This is R, after all. Things shld be fine if you're not going to be bit-shifting values.